# Como listar uma amostra de todas as tabelas em um banco MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query, sql-select, select

Preciso fazer uma amostra de todas as tabelas em um banco MySQL, por exemplo através de um `SELECT * ... LIMIT 10`.

Já tenho o código que retorna todas as tabelas da database atual:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = database();
```

A consulta (incorreta) a seguir ilustra o que desejo fazer:

```
Select * from ( 
    select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = database()
 ) limit 10;
```

, a qual funcionaria como:

```
Select * from tabela1 limit 10;
Select * from tabela2 limit 10;
...
Select * from tabelaN limit 10;
```

Como posso fazer isso em uma query só?

Encontrei exemplos que falam de cursores, mas não tenho certeza sobre como poderia aplicá-los neste caso.

Vi um exemplo bem semelhante em SQL Server usando cursores, mas não consegui adaptá-lo pra MySQL.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acho que somente com uma [procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) ou [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html).

Comment: Acho que dá pra fazer com um select comum sim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com a seguinte query você conseguirá o que você precisa:

```
Select concat("SELECT * FROM ", table_name, " LIMIT 10;") 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = database()
```

Ela retornará todas as querys que você desejo rodar, listando todas as tabelas e contatenando com o `SELECT * FROM <tabela>`

Para executar essas querys, é possível criar uma `procedure` que irá executar as querys retornadas pela consulta anterior. Talvez exista alguma forma melhor de estruturar essa `procedure` (parametrizar os limites e a consulta do cursor por exemplo), mas do jeito que está funciona :)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `tablesPreview`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE queryToExecute varchar(255);
    DECLARE tablesCursor
        CURSOR FOR
        SELECT concat("SELECT * FROM ", table_name, " LIMIT 10;") 
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = database();

    DECLARE
        CONTINUE HANDLER FOR
        SQLSTATE '02000'
            SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN tablesCursor;

    myLoop: LOOP
        FETCH tablesCursor INTO queryToExecute;

        IF done THEN
            CLOSE tablesCursor;
            LEAVE myLoop;
        END IF;

    set @query = (SELECT queryToExecute);

    PREPARE tablePreviewQuery FROM @query;
    EXECUTE tablePreviewQuery;

    END LOOP;

END
```

Comment: Obrigado @gmsantos! Esta query é a primeira parte do que quero. O que desejo é o resultado da execução de todas elas. Há alguma forma compacta de trazer não a lista de SELECTs, mas os resultados de todos eles?

Comment: Pesquisei bastante sobre isso e não encontrei nada tão simples. Como as colunas das tabelas podem ser diferentes isso dificulta um `UNION ALL` para executar o resultado da query.

Comment: Você está usando alguma linguagem backend? Com php consigo facilmente exibir o resultado dessas querys.

Comment: No meu caso não há necessidade de um `UNION ALL`, porque não preciso que seja em um único _recordset_. O resultado que eu espero é exatamente o que obtenho ao executar a lista de `SELECT`, e ter isso salvo em uma _procedure_, p.ex. `sp_amostra_bd`.

O resultado é para exibição no próprio MySQL Workbench, então não tenho como usar outra linguagem para auxiliar.

Comment: @Ulisses consegui implementar numa procedure a lógica para execução.

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente o que eu procurava! Não imaginei que fosse resultar em uma _procedure_ tão extensa, se soubesse que seria tão trabalhoso!... Mas agora ficou bem simples, basta um `CALL tablesPreview;` e pronto. Muito obrigado!

Ah, sou novo aqui no StackOverflow. Há algo mais que posso fazer, além de setar a sua resposta como útil e aceita (setinha para cima e marca "V" verde)?

Comment: @Ulisses basicamente é isso mesmo que você pode fazer. O que você pode fazer a mais é oferecer uma [gratificação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), só que é preciso que você tenha mais reputação.

Comment: Pena, estou pobrinho ainda, com 28 pontos... Muito obrigado pelo tempo gasto em me ajudar!